# Hive partitioned view not showing partitions info

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, cloudera, hive-partitions

I have created a partitioned view in Hive as below

```
create view if not exists view_name
PARTITIONED ON(date)
as
select col1,col2,date
from table1
union all
select col1,col2,date
from table2
```

The underlying tables are partitioned on 'date' column. When I use `DESCRIBE FORMATTED VIEW_NAME` I could see the partitions information as null as showin in screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv6wk.png)

If I use SHOW CREATE TABLE View_Name, I get view definition without partitions as below

```
create view if not exists view_name
as
select col1,col2,date
from table1
union all
select col1,col2,date
from table2
```

Please let me know what I am missing

Answer (score 1):

From the hive documentation

> Although there is currently no connection between the view partition
>   and underlying table partitions, Hive does provide dependency
>   information as part of the hook invocation for ALTER VIEW ADD
>   PARTITION. It does this by compiling an internal query of the form

in the other words, there is no partition information available in the views about the underlying tables. A workaround (depending how complex is your view query) is add the partitions as follow

```
ALTER VIEW view_name ADD [IF NOT EXISTS] partition_spec partition_spec
```

At least from the user perspective, it will provide information  about the available partitions in the underlying tables.